# `stringr::str_view` errors with Bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown

Given with this

````
```{r}
stringr::str_view(c("alice", "bob"), "o")
```
````

I get an error:

```
Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting latex output.
Please change the output type of this document to HTML. Alternatively, you can allow
HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of
your rmarkdown file:

  always_allow_html: yes

Note however that the HTML output will not be visible in non-HTML formats.
```

Why is bookdown complaining about this? It seems that `stringr::str_view` is being executed unnecessarily.

EDIT: The desired result is a PDF with the `stringr::str_view(c("alice", "bob"), "o")` text and syntax highlighting.

Comment: What is the desired result? You are trying to output to latex but include a function designed for interactive use that produces HTML output in your notebook. If it is being called "unnecessarily", remove or comment the line from your code?

Comment: @CalumYou The desired result is a PDF with the `stringr::str_view(c("alice", "bob"), "o")` text and syntax highlighting. Do you know the right syntax to achieve this? (Therefore, I do not want `stringr::str_view` to run.)

Comment: This is not trivial as far as I can tell - the source of `str_view` uses entirely HTML to display the output; it doesn't save an image that could be displayed in a knitted document.

Answer (score 1):

See Section 2.10 on HTMl Widgets in the **bookdown** book at https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html-widgets.html. Basically you need to install the **webshot** package and PhantomJS.

If you have enabled caching (via the chunk option `cache=TRUE`, e.g., https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/578), you have to remove cache files and rebuild the book.